Split Videos and/or Image Sequences using Video Players
Say I am using a video player like mpv, PotPlayer, VLC, and MPC-HC. I created a segment of a video by setting Mark A and Mark B. Now I want to split that segment from the video or make an image sequence out of it using the video player. How do I do that?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Video players bookmarks are meant for positioning quickly to points
of interest within the video. For editing videos, you need a video
editor.
Example free editor is
Shotcut,
but see also
Free Shotcut Alternatives for Windows.

For VLC specifically, you could use its transcoding features
to transcode a part of the video by specifying the exact start and
end times:

